# Reorganize a string. Split digits from text

Tags: string, python-3.x, digits

While scraping a website i received from the `get_text()`in Beautifulsoup :

```
protein  30 %, crude fibres  2.6 %, fat content  15 %, crude ash  7.7 %, Vitamin E  180 mg/kg, omega-3 fatty acids  1.5 %, omega-6 fatty acids  1.4 %
```

The aim is to get a csv looking like :

```
protein ; 30%
crude fibres ; 2,6%
fat content ; 15 %
...
omega-6 fatty acids ; 1,4%
```

But i need to keep my logics of scrapping. 
That's why i need to create `pair_list=[name,quantity]` like `pair_list=[protein,30%]`

How can i create such a pair ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you always have that two space separator:

```
>>> s = 'protein  30 %, crude fibres  2.6 %, fat content  15 %, crude ash  7.7 %, Vitamin E  180 mg/kg, omega-3 fatty acids  1.5 %, omega-6 fatty acids  1.4 %'
>>> [x.strip().split('  ') for x in s.split(',')]
[['protein', '30 %'], ['crude fibres', '2.6 %'], ['fat content', '15 %'], ['crude ash', '7.7 %'], ['Vitamin E', '180 mg/kg'], ['omega-3 fatty acids', '1.5 %'], ['omega-6 fatty acids', '1.4 %']]

>>> for x in _:
        print(x)

['protein', '30 %']
['crude fibres', '2.6 %']
['fat content', '15 %']
['crude ash', '7.7 %']
['Vitamin E', '180 mg/kg']
['omega-3 fatty acids', '1.5 %']
['omega-6 fatty acids', '1.4 %']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split` within a list comprehension :

```
>>> [re.split(r' (?=\d+)',i) for i in s.split(',')]
[['protein ', '30 %'], [' crude fibres ', '2.6 %'], [' fat content ', '15 %'], [' crude ash ', '7.7 %'], [' Vitamin E ', '180 mg/kg'], [' omega-3 fatty acids ', '1.5 %'], [' omega-6 fatty acids ', '1.4 %']]
```

The regex `r' (?=\d+)'` use a [*positive look-ahead*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) which makes the `re.split` split your regex based on a space that followed by a number.

And then you can write the result to a `csv` file :

```
import csv
with open('my_file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerows(list_result)
```